# How do I perform save on all records in Django?

Tags: django

In one of my models I want to add a field that depends on other fields of the same model and will be calculated when the record is saved.

In my database there are already records, so I thought that I could accomplish this by performing `save`. I have tried `save` on a single record and it seems to work.

For more records can I use a loop like this:

```
for each_product_record in Product.objects.all():
    each_product_record.save()
```

Is there a better way or are there any caveats I should know before hand ?

Comment: -----------------------no--------------------------